# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I have a python project and want to write a command line launcher.  My project works fine when I run tests or launch from my IDE (pycharm).  However when I try to launch via the command line I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python'` error.

Here is my directory structure:

```
.
├── Makefile
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── README.md
├── create_jenkins_jobs.sh
└── python
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── create_credentials.py
    ├── create_jenkins_jobs_cli.py
    ├── credential_builder.py
    ├── jenkins_multibranch_job_builder.py
    ├── templates
    │   ├── job.xml
    │   ├── multibranch_job_template.xml
    │   ├── ssh_cred_template.xml
    │   └── user_pw_cred_template.xml
    └── tests
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── integration
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   ├── build_credential_test.py
        │   ├── build_job_test.py
        │   ├── conftest.py
        │   ├── test_id_rsa
        │   └── test_id_rsa.pub
        └── unit
```

The shell script `create_jenkins_jobs.sh` contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 python/create_jenkins_jobs_cli.py "${@}"
```

the file `create_jenkins_jobs_cli.py` contains the following code:

```py
from typing import Set
from shared.common import preflight_env_check

from python.jenkins_multibranch_job_builder import JenkinsMultibranchJobBuilder
def configure_jenkins_jobs(git_repos: Set[str]):
    jenkins_job_builder = JenkinsMultibranchJobBuilder(jenkins_server_url=JENKINS_BASE_SERVER_URL,
                                                       jenkins_folder=JENKINS_ROOT_JOB_FOLDER,
                                                       user=JENKINS_USER, token=JENKINS_TOKEN,
                                                       git_cred_id=GIT_SSH_CRED_ID,
                                                       git_repos=git_repos)
    jenkins_job_builder.configure_jobs()


configure_jenkins_jobs(GIT_REPOS)
```

When I launch `create_jenkins_jobs.sh` or `create_jenkins_jobs_cli.py` I always get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python'
```

```
$>./create_jenkins_jobs.sh
/Users/pswenson/dev/cc-cicd-automation/.venv/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'python/create_jenkins_jobs_cli.py' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python/create_jenkins_jobs_cli')
```

I've tried all sorts of different techniques to get this to work with PYTHONPATH, working directories, etc...

It seems there is something basic about how python modules work that I don't understand.

Comment: It's the directory the main script lives in, not the current working directory, that is automatically added to the Python path. There is no package named `python` *in* the directory `./python`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does changing the line:

```
from python.jenkins_multibranch_job_builder import JenkinsMultibranchJobBuilder
```

to

```
from jenkins_multibranch_job_builder import JenkinsMultibranchJobBuilder
```

Sort you?

Comment: I knew it was something dumb, thanks.  turned out that pycharm was configured in such as way that ^^^ didn't work unless I referenced python as a module.... so when I did ^^^ pycharm broke but was easy to fix.